# Git : how avoiding a wrong push

Tags: git, git-push

How can I prevent *myself* pushing on a specific branch (master) of a specific remote (test) ?

I still want to be able to push this branch on other remotes, and other branches on this remote. And others should still be able to push on this branch of this remote.

For those who would ask why :

Among others, I have a remote named test, with two branches : master, and release.

Other developers are using test and push normally on it, on master.

I make parallel developments, that always should go to release. Even if I'm working on master locally.
So I want to be sure that running `git push test` fails.

**edit**

My .git/config file (extract) :

```
[remote "test"]
    url = ssh://...
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/test/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/release:refs/remotes/test/release
    push = HEAD:master
```

Looking at it first would have avoided me to create a hook (see [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37320197/2955802)).

Comment: You can create a git hook to prevent it from happening, or change your branch workflow to something like git flow so you never touch master at all

Comment: If you are using a host like GitHub, you can configure it to reject direct pushes to certain branches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't use GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

(using method from @RobbieAverill's comment)

You can write a `pre-push` hook, testing specific cases.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == 'test' ]
then
    grep 'refs/heads/master' > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo '*** PUSH DENIED, see hooks/pre-push !!! ***'
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Copy the code above in a file named `.git/hooks/pre-push`, and set this file executable :

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push
```

Now, `git push test HEAD:master` echoes the message and refuses the push.

You can force it (bypassing the hook) by using `--no-verify` : `git push --no-verify test HEAD:master`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, in fact, I just had to remove the

```
push=HEAD:master
```

line from my .git/config file.

I set up this line far ago, when *I* was publishing by push on test.

`git push test` then doesn't push anything anymore, asking for an explicit branch to push on.

Editing my question, and keeping other answer for reference.